# Find a common class python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

Having two python instances of some classes, let's say a is an instance of class A, and b is an instance of class B, is there an easy way to look for a common class for both objects? Also, since of course, all in Python inherits from 'object' I would like to know what the most 'specialized' common class.

I tried the following code, which seems to work:

```
def common_class(a,b):
    A = a.__class__
    B = b.__class__
    for i in A.mro():
        if i in B.mro():
            return i
```

But I was wondering if there exists an easier way to do it.

Comment: Maybe check the types of the objects?

Comment: Mmm... Could you elaborate? I don't see how to get the result that way.

Comment: Well, there only say that I can use mro to get all the parents of my class, but I'm already doing that. I want to know if there an easier way, not only to get all the parents but to check for common parents of two classes.

Comment: @Gaussian97 Okay I got it, it will not work for that condition.

Comment: @Gaussian97 you're correct. I flagged your question for being a duplicate, which I have since retracted, because on second thought I realized that. But I forgot to delete the automatic comment. Can't help you any further, sorry.